# First Installation

Tags: system-installation

What set of software packages should I install? There are so many choices which I can't get any clear guidance on what is suitable. I am stuck on the install options for 16.04 after core services have been installed. There is a list of 20+ configurations many I can discount. I tried an install just essential system services and Xubuntu desktop and this failed. Something to do with LVM not configured. So re-installing afresh no LVM this time, whole HDD. Just need advice on what I should opt for. Any pointers - see below,

**USE OF LAPTOP**

I am setting up a basic office laptop on an old Dell Pentium 1.73 Ghz 512 MB 40Gig HDD for my Charity Cruse. We are using it an isolated office where our volunteers support clients. Main need is for browser to access/show a shared Google Calendar which has the room booking, so they can enter a new booking when with the client. It should also have email and Skype. Libre Office a possible advantage Word/Excel only. Finally, remotely accessing it by an administrator would be an advantage but not essential.

BigAde

Comment: It sounds like you use a server installation?! I would recommend you use a Xubuntu iso for installation and then you can add software as desired.

Comment: Hi Kev I using the basic CD install which uses my internet to actively link to the GB server.

Comment: installation of Xubuntu without LVM hangs on start up with:

/dev/sdal: clean, 57455/2411920 files, 438437/9638400 blocks

which I had on the first attempt as an extra line after the LVM comment

Comment: With basic you mean `minimal`? If yes: That's what I meant. If no: Please specify what image you use, e.g. post a link to that image. In any case, if you want to use a full desktop environment, use an image with it.

Comment: Please also add more information about your CPU, if you have a running (live)system add the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. Maybe it is not working because your CPU is not supporting PAE

Comment: I created the 48MB installation link see 32 bit 16.04 on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: cat /proc/cpuinfo

gave list of characteristics including a flag for PAE but failed/timed out on 

DEPEND  dependency for /dev/disk/by.....
and
DEPEND dependency for swap

Comment: Looks like an general ISO problem see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1627950

Comment: How do I flag my specific issue. Unfortunately no means to use the log on the laptop being converted

Answer (score 2):

I try to make a followable answer, but I want to point out, that it would be way easier if you install Xubuntu with that [image](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/16.04/release/xubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso). It has many advantages, e.g. a graphical installer

I downloaded the minimal image and installed it in a VM:

- Put in your CD and boot from that
- Choose your installation language
- Choose your country and locale
- Choose your keyboard layout
- Enter your hostname
- Choose your nearest mirror for downloading the packages
- Enter a proxy or blank for none (I use none)
- Create a new user (I did not use home-encryption)
- Choose your timezone
- Partitioning (I used the entire disk, no LVM)
- Wait until the base system is downloaded
- Choose the update method (I choose "No automatic updates" but maybe for you you should choose something else)

---

I think your question is based on the next window
[image]

Since you are not able to install `Xubuntu Desktop` I recommend you just hit TAB, to focus `continue` to continue. This will only install the `standard system utilities`-package.

- Install `GRUB` in MBR
- Set system clock
- Reboot your system

After the reboot you are able to login to your new installation of Ubuntu.

If you are now able to ping any website, you can install anything you want from the repositories.

```
ping -c2 www.google.com
```

Otherwise you have other problems and you should ask another question after searching the forum.

First of all you should update your system, even if you just installed it

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Lets install Xubuntu ontop of that minimal Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop -y
```

That will download about 2.4G of packages and could take a while.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server # This is for remote administration
```

Now type in `reboot` to reboot. After the reboot your desktop should look like this

[image]

I think and hope that is all. Everything you need, except skype should be now installed.

Comment: Hi Kev Thank you for such a detailed and comprehensive reply. I really appreciate it. Since I am 90% of the way with the CD/internet install I will go with that. If it fails again I will then revert to your original suggestion and write the image to a DVD. Once again my thanks for all the guidance.

Comment: You are welcome, I hope it helps you. BTW don't waste a DVD, use a USB-pendrive. The installation is much faster and you don't have trash because you can reuse it. But not every pendrive is working